# How to read "n" lines at a time from stdin?

Tags: python, stdin, readline, readlines

Consider the stdin has the following entries:

```
2  
a     
b     
3
d   
e   
f
```

Now I would like to first read the number using `n= sys.stdin.readline()` 
and then read the next `n` lines using a function `ReadNLines(n)` into a list.

So the expected output is:

```
List1 = ['a','b']  
List2 = ['d','e','f']
```

Here is what I have tried. And I am looking for better timing performance.

```
import sys
def ReadNLines(n):
    List =[]
    for line in range(n):
        List.append(sys.stdin.readline())
    return List

if __name__ == "__main__":
    n = sys.stdin.readline()
    List1 = ReadNLines(n)
    n = sys.stdin.readline()
    List2 = ReadNLines(n)
```

Comment: "Is this possible?" I would imagine so.  What have you tried?

Comment: Are you getting any errors? Can you please show us what you've tried?

Comment: Why use `sys.stdin.readline()` instead of `input()`?

Comment: Read a line, convert it to an integer. Then read the next `n` lines in a loop.

Comment: FYI, `readlines(n)` doesn't read `n` lines. It reads `n` bytes, then splits it into lines.

Comment: @Barmar I would like to have a custom ReadNLines function that could read n lines. Please see my updated post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to remove the newline that `sys.stdin.readline()` includes in the result. And you need to convert `n` to an integer.

```
import sys
def ReadNLines(n):
    List =[]
    for _ in range(n):
        List.append(sys.stdin.readline().strip())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    n = int(sys.stdin.readline().strip())
    ReadNLines(n)
    n = int(sys.stdin.readline().strip())
    ReadNLines(n)
```

Since you never use the `line` variable, the convention is to use `_` as a dummy variable. You can also convert the function into a list comprehension:

```
def readNLines(n):
    return [sys.stdin.readline().strip() for _ in range(n)]
```

Comment: Yes, I understand. But I would like to have a better timing performance than calling sys.stdin.readline n times.

Comment: Why do you think that's a performance issue? I can't think of any other way to do it.

Comment: You could use `sys.stdin.read()` and then call `splitlines()`, but this will read all of stdin, not just the specified number of lines.

Comment: I was wondering if there is any other way which takes lesser time.

Comment: I understand what you mean by "better timing performance". I can't think of anything. And first you need to make it correct before worrying about timing.

Comment: Yes. Is there any way in which we can achieve a faster performance in the code you have suggested. That is, instead of calling sys.stdin.readline() n times.

Comment: How could there be such a thing? You can't do it by reading a number of bytes, because you don't know how many bytes there are in the lines. If you go too far, there's no way to back up.

Answer (score 1):

I think this does what you want:

```
import sys

def read_n_lines(n):
    return [sys.stdin.readline().rstrip() for _ in range(n)]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    count = 0
    while True:
        n = sys.stdin.readline().rstrip()
        if not n:  # Blank line entered?
            break  # Quit.
        n = int(n)
        result = read_n_lines(n)
        count += 1
        print(f'List{count} = {result}')
    print('done')
```

Sample run — <kbd>Enter</kbd> key was pressed to end each line of input:

```
2
a
b
List1 = ['a', 'b']
3
d
e
f
List2 = ['d', 'e', 'f']

done
```